# Access helper setter in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let us say I have a helper like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def foo
    @foo
  end

  def set_foo(foo)
    @foo = foo
  end

  def foo=(foo)
    @foo = foo
  end
end
```

and a controller like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ApplicationHelper

  def index
    foo = 'hello'
  end
end
```

I wonder to know why in the controller neither `foo = 'hello'`, nor `foo=('hello')` invokes the helper's method `foo=` but `set_foo 'hello'` does invoke its method `set_foo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is, it will just set a local variable in the controller method called `foo`.

If you call `self.foo = 'hello'` Ruby will know that foo is a method that should be called.

Worth noting is that this is a completely wrong usage of Rails view helpers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. For sure it is wrong, just wanted to understand what was going on.

Comment: I +1'd for you! I love your cat pic